# Creating forms with Pyramid web framework and Jinja2 templates

Tags: python, rest, templates, jinja2, pyramid

I am a newbie trying to build a simple web framework to support a SQLAlchemy DB. I am using `Pyramid` and `Jinja2` templates. I am planning on using server-side rendering of static `HTML` instead of `JSON`. I have gone over the [Pyramid tutorials](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/) repeatedly, spent days on [JINJA's website](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/), looked up questions here on good ol' Stack, but haven't been able to gather a clear understanding of how to achieve the following:

My issue at the moment is how to create a `template` that adds created objects using the `get()` method. I am having a hard time figuring out how to add these objects using the `JINJA2` template syntax, e.g. `{{ name }}` in a form.

Here is a snippet example of the `route`, `view` and `template`:

## CODE:

**__init__.py**

Each entity that makes up an `assessment` in the db, e.g. `user`, `element`s, `video`, `categories`, etc. have routes like this:

```
config.add_route('assessments', '/assessments')
config.add_route('assessment', '/assessments/{id}')
```

**views.py**

The design for the RESTful API is the same for **EVERY** entity mentioned above:

```
@view_defaults(route_name='assessments', renderer='templates/editor_view.jinja2') # editor view for creating assessment
class AssessmentsViews(object):
    API = api
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        assessments = self.API.retrieve_assessments()
        return {}

    @view_config(request_method='POST')
    def post_assessment(self):
        name = self.request.params['name']
        text = self.request.params['text']
        user = self.request.params['username']
        video = self.request.params['videoname']
        catogories = self.request.params['category_names']
        assessment = self.API.create_assessment(name, text, user, video, categories)
        return HTTPAccepted(location = request.route_url('assessments/{id}'))

@view_defaults(route_name='assessment', renderer='templates/user_view.jinja2') #user_view for the user to take the assessment
class AssessmentViews(object):
    API = api
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def get_assessment(self):
        assessment_id = int(self.request.matchdict['id'])
        assessment = self.API.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id)
        return {'name': assessment.name, 'text': assessment.text, 'user': assessment.user, 'video':assessment.video, 'categories': assessment.categories}

    @view_config(request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        assessment = self.get_assessment()
        if assessment is None:
            raise HTTPNotFound()
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('/assessments/{id}'))

    @view_config(request_method='PUT')
    #code

    @view_config(request_method='DELETE')
    #code
```

**template**

A template meant for a user to enter their ratings (take an assessment), but how does one add the categories to the form?  Is it by a redirect? or by JINJA code?

```
  # add {{categories}} from Assessment where in this form?

    <form method='POST' action ='/category_ratings'>
      <dl>
        <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> {{category}} </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int, '') }}</dd>
        <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Rating </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
        <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Rating </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
        <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Rating </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
        <dd><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></dd>
      </dl>
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *But how does one retrieve the assessment???* Also I suggest use professional tone and not excessive quotation marks when asking questions as this implies the person asking  the question is putting some effort himself/herself.

Comment: Didn't mean for it to come off poorly with quotation marks, apologies for that. I just added the `return {'name': Assessment.name}` which should allow Jinja templates to call these items into my template via `{{name}}`. Still working on it right now.

Comment: In your `get()` method you should return a dictionary of variables which will be available in the template. E.g. `{"name": assesment.name}`

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa how would I use {{name}} in a template, specifically a form like the one above?